# How can i define a command output as a ENV in Dockerfile

Tags: php, laravel, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

I have a php-laravel application and I want to deploy this application to container. So, I wrote a Dockerfile. With this line

```
RUN php artisan key:generate
```

APP_KEY generated and saved in .env. But I couldnt see this env when I wrote `echo $APP_KEY` in the container. It turned empty

Then I added an ENV line in Dockerfile like this:

```
ENV APP_KEY=$(grep "APP_KEY=base64" .env | sed -e 's/APP_KEY=//g')
```

But it still isn't working. When I try this command in container's command line, it's working.
And I tried one more time and I use more simple command like

```
ENV APP_KEY=$(pwd)
```

it turns
`$(pwd)` not current directory.

Briefly, How can I define a key=value line in .env (for example APP_KEY=... line) as an ENV in Dockerfile